# Input returns None when using function to print a string with a delay

Tags: python, string, input, return, console-application

This is a followup question for my delayed prints. But this time I am stuck when I am trying to input the print_with_delay(text) function. It returns None after the print happened and before I can input anything in the console. What is a way to tackle this problem?

The code:

```
import time

# Delay text function to create realism for console dialogues
# Counts the length of the string and applies this to the delay
# Greatly improves visibility in the code
# No more time.sleep() between all print dialogues
def print_with_delay(text):
    delay = len(text) / 100 + 1.2
    time.sleep(delay)
    print(text)
    # if not text:
    #    return text

def start_game():
    username = input(print_with_delay("Hello adventurer, I am Tony Tales, and what is your name?"))
    print_with_delay(f"Nice to meet you {username}.")
    print_with_delay("They call me Tony Tales, because I am a very talented tale teller.")
    create_story = input (print_with_delay("I can sense greatness from you. Would you like to create a story with me? [Y/N]"))
    
    if create_story == "y" or create_story == "Y":
        print_with_delay("Great!")
    else:
        print_with_delay("Oooh? That is disappointing. Here, take this!")
        print_with_delay("Tony Tales stabs you with a Pointy Pen...")
        print_with_delay("You feel dizzy and faint...")
        print_with_delay("The story ended.")
        exit()
```

The output:

```
Hello adventurer, I am Tony Tales, and what is your name?
NoneTim
Nice to meet you Tim.
They call me Tony Tales, because I am a very talented tale teller.
I can sense greatness from you. Would you like to create a story with me? [Y/N]
NoneY
Great!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a single, generic `with_delay` function that will run an *arbitrary* function, with the given argument, after a delay. You can have it default to `print` to simulate `print_with_delay`.

```
def with_delay(text, f=print):
    delay = len(text) / 100 + 1.2
    time.sleep(delay)
    return f(text)


def start_game():
    username = with_delay("Hello adventurer, I am Tony Tales, and what is your name?", input)
    with_delay(f"Nice to meet you {username}.")
    with_delay("They call me Tony Tales, because I am a very talented tale teller.")
    create_story = with_delay("I can sense greatness from you. Would you like to create a story with me? [Y/N]")
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that was possible. Was it such a silly question that it gets downvoted? I tried to find similiar posts, but I couldn't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

replace first 2 lines of `start_game` with below:

```
username = input("Hello adventurer, I am Tony Tales, and what is your name? ")
print_with_delay(f"Nice to meet you %s ." % username)
```

you need to remove `print_with_delay` from input as it is a function that returns `None`

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I want to apply a delay on every text that is going to be displayed. The string before inputs as well.

Comment: @Tim then put `time.sleep(2)` before `username` line

Comment: I was trying to avoid time.sleep() to prevent messy code and automate delays. So are you saying that it isn't possible what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are using `print_with_delay` to output the prompt, you don't need to pass a prompt string to `input`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I have tried it before. And it works like it should. But I had hoped there was another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chepner mentioned, the input() method doesn't require a string argument.

It works like this:

```
def start_game():
    print_with_delay("Hello adventurer, I am Tony Tales, and what is your name?")
    username = input()
    print_with_delay(f"Nice to meet you {username}.")
    print_with_delay("They call me Tony Tales, because I am a very talented tale teller.")
    print_with_delay("I can sense greatness from you. Would you like to create a story with me? [Y/N]")
    create_story = input()
```

I had hoped there was another way to fix it. But this will do the job for now.

**Edit:**

What is shown above is a workaround. Check @Chepner his answer for a better solution.